# unix utility to limit the number of bytes placed into a bash variable

Tags: bash

Is there a unix/linux utility, perhaps a shell builtin or an external command, that will limit the number of bytes placed into a bash variable? For example, I want to make sure `STRING` gets at most 1000 bytes (or some arbitrary number I choose) from the output of the `curl` (or other) command:

`STRING=$(curl -s http://localhost:8010/status?)`

Let me edit this to make clear that I'm just using curl as an example, but I'd like this to work with any command.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `-r 0-1000` to your curl commandline, i.e.:

```
STRING=$(curl -r 0-1000 -s http://localhost:8010/status?)
```

Or generically you can use `head -c 1000`, i.e.:

```
STRING=$(curl -s http://localhost:8010/status? | head -c 1000)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I'm looking for something more generic that will work with any command.

Comment: Why not use the native argument in curl?

Comment: because I don't want to restrict it to curl